# How was $[T]_{\beta}$ computed here? (change of basis and linear transformations)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a little unclear about a simple step.  Let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and say $\beta = \{(1, 1)^T, (1, -1)^T\}$ and $\beta^{'} = \{(2, 4)^T, (3, 1)^T\}$ are two ordered bases for the space.  I have a linear transformation $T((a, b)^T) = (3a-b, a+3b)^T$ and it says that $[T]_{\beta} = \begin{bmatrix} 3&1\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}$ but I get something different.  How was this computed?

My work is as follows:

$T(\beta) = T((1, 1)^T), T((1, -1)^T)$ which yields $\begin{bmatrix} 2&4\\4&-2\end{bmatrix}$

I see that it works if I use the standard basis vectors by putting them through $T$ and then use the resulting vectors as rows of my matrix, but I do not understand why that would be correct as opposed to what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you may have forgotten is that you have to re-express the output vectors in terms of the basis vectors, because the matrix keeps track of what happens to each individual basis vector.

So if I plug in $(1,1)$ in to $T$ using your formula, I do get $(2,4)$, but this is not telling me what $T$ does to these coordinates, it tells me what $T$ does to the vector $(1,1)$ with respect to basis $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$, since $(2,4) = 2(1,0) + 4(0,1)$. You want to describe things in terms of the basis $\beta$. To express what this does to the given basis, and hence to talk about $T$ with respect to basis $\beta$, we have to figure out which linear combination of vectors $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ make $(2,4)$, and these will form the column of the matrix. It is easy to see that $3(1,1) -1(1,-1) = (2,4)$, and so the first column of the matrix should indeed be $(1,-1)^T$.

Can you do the other column now?

Comment: yes of course, thank you!